# Transfering text

Tags: text

I need to transfer section 5.3 after the pictures but \pagebreak and \vspace seem to do nothing
[image]

```
enter code here begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{Immagini/opt gen}
\caption{Data comparison technique.}
 \end{figure}
  \begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{Immagini/opt variables}
\caption{Data comparison technique.}
    \end{figure}
     
    \begin{figure} [h!]
    \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.70]{Immagini/opt termination}
        \caption{Data comparison technique.}
        \end{figure}
     As for the termination parameter, this can be express as: the ratio between of the sum of 
         the squared difference between the simulation values and the experimental ones at the 
        end of the data matching and the its initial value must be less than or equal to a 
              fixed value (i.e. 0.05)
         \begin{equation}
            \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}((y_{i}-\bar{y})^{2})_{fin}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}((y_{i}- 
            \bar{y})^{2})_{in}}=\epsilon
           \end{equation}
    \begin{figure} [h!]
     \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{Immagini/opt obj}
  \caption{Data comparison technique.}
      \end{figure}
           The final objective is to achieve a data matching according to the termination 
               parameters and the boundary conditions set.
             \vspace{100mm}
            \section{Conclusion}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class employ.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{report}

Comment: Have you triead loading the [placeins](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package? Loading it should prevent floats from section being after the `\section` directives of the following section.

Comment: yep but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you give `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` a try?

Comment: It works. I forgot to put [section]. Thank you so much